# Perl must do break return to calling code line outside recursive

Tags: perl, recursion

How in Perl do we do break return to calling code line outside recursive function (sub), when inside recursive, in some nested depth on runtime

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Could you add an example?

Comment: `return`......?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you arrange your code to immediately return after the recursive call if the value returned by the recursive call indicates this should be done.

For example, the following returns immediately after visiting the left subbranch of the tree if it contains the node. It doesn't proceed to check the right subbranch.

```perl
use feature qw( current_sub say );

sub search {
   my $root = shift;
   my $val  = shift;

   my $helper = sub {
      my $node = shift
         or return undef;

      $node->{ val } eq $val
         and return $node;

      return __SUB__->( $node->{ left  } )
         ||  __SUB__->( $node->{ right } );
      );
   };

   return $helper->( $root );
}

my $found = search($node, $val);
```

---

It would be unusual to do so, but you could use exceptions or `last` to immediately jump out.

Using exception:

```perl
sub search {
   my $root = shift;
   my $val  = shift;

   my $found;

   my $helper = sub {
      my $node = shift
         or return;

      if ( $node->{ val } eq $val ) {
         $found = $node;
         die("FOUND\n");
      }

      __SUB__->( $node->{ left  } );
      __SUB__->( $node->{ right } );
   };

   eval { $helper->( $root ) };
   die $@ if $@ && $@ ne "FOUND\n";
   return $found;
}
```

Using `last`:

```perl
sub search {
   my $root = shift;
   my $val  = shift;

   my $found;

   my $helper = sub {
      my $node = shift
         or return;

      if ( $node->{ val } eq $val ) {
         $found = $node;
         no warnings qw( exiting );
         last SEARCH;
      }

      __SUB__->( $node->{ left  } );
      __SUB__->( $node->{ right } );
   };

   SEARCH: { $helper->( $root ) };
   return $found;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a simple `return` by using a stack instead of recursion.

```perl
sub search {
   my $root = shift;
   my $val  = shift;

   my @todo = $root;
   while ( @todo ) {
      my $node = pop( @todo )
         or next;

      $node->{ val } eq $val
         and return $node;

      push @todo, $node->@{qw( left right )};
   }

   return undef;
}
```